# Style common group of divs in one css statement

Tags: javascript, css

I have a few divs created dynamically in Javascript.I was wondering if it is possible to style them all at once.

```
#somediv {
    background-color: #F2F5FC;
    border-style:solid;
    border-bottom:thin dotted #33ccff;
}

#somediv2 {
    background-color: #F2F5FC;
    border-style:solid;
    border-bottom:thin dotted #33ccff;
}
```

...and so on (this can be even 50 divs)

I would like to change this to something like:

```
 #somediv* {
    background-color: #F2F5FC;
    border-style:solid;
    border-bottom:thin dotted #33ccff;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are going to be styled exactly the same, use a class, [look here for the difference](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php):

```
.divClass {
    background-color: #F2F5FC;
    border-style:solid;
    border-bottom:thin dotted #33ccff;
}
```

Then your divs are like this:

```
<div id="somediv" class="divClass"></div>
<div id="somediv2" class="divClass"></div>
```

Just edit your script to include the class attribute, by far the easiest solution...and this is **exactly** what classes are for :)

Answer (score 4):

Give your dynamically created div's a class, then style the class. Or maybe if you're inserting your new divs into a container you could just select based on that:

```
<div id='stuff_goes_here'>
  <!-- ... dynamic divs will go here ... -->
</div>
```

and then:

```
#stuff_goes_here div {
  /* ... styles ... */
}
```

Comment: How come I didn't think of this. Genius:)

Answer (score 1):

This is what the class attribute was created to handle. Give all of your divs the same class and you can say something like:

```
.divclass {
    background-color: #F2F5FC;
    border-style:solid;
    border-bottom:thin dotted #33ccff;
}
```

But if you REALLY need to do what you asked, you can use a new form of selector. The following will match all IDs that start with 'somediv', but this won't work on older browsers:

```
[id^=somediv] {
    background-color: #F2F5FC;
    border-style:solid;
    border-bottom:thin dotted #33ccff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#somediv, #somediv2 {
    background-color: #F2F5FC;
    border-style:solid;
    border-bottom:thin dotted #33ccff;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if I have 50 divs?

Comment: Then as others have suggested, use a class, or type a lot of commas.

Comment: @Vafello, then you can use -depending on your audience- CSS's `starts-with` selector (see my answer), although a common class would be so much more functional and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest using a `class`, since that's what they're for; you can, though, do it as you want to:

```
div[id^=somediv]
{
/* css styles */
}
```

Using the CSS `starts-with` selector (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors), although it relies on CSS 3 (I think) implementation in your user/audience.